# A question about dual representations, kernels and notations used in Bishop's book.

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I'm having hard times about kernel functions and dual representations on 'Pattern recognition from and machine learning' by Bishop. Here it is the page I'm trying to understand:[image]

Of course setting the gradient of $J(\textbf{w})$ to $\textbf{0}$ and solving for $\textbf{w}$ leads to the (6.3). Now he writes about the design matrix $\Phi$.

For me (without initially considering nonlinear transformations of dataset), the design Matrix $\textbf{X}$ is a $N \times D$ matrix with ($n$- number of samples, $D$- number of components/features)

$$\textbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(1)}  & \dots  & x_1^{(D)}\\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ x_n^{(1)} \quad & \dots & \quad x_n^{(D)} \end{bmatrix}$$

Considering a (possibly nonlinear) transformation $\phi: \, \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^K$ such that
$$
\mathbb{R}^D \ni \textbf{x}=(x^{(1)}, \dots , x^{(D)}) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}\phi_1(\textbf{x}), \dots , \phi_K(\textbf{x}) \end{bmatrix}$$

I'm assuming the application $\phi$ takes a ROW-vector and brings a ROW vector because I originally assumed that the $D$- dimensional features of matrix $\textbf{X}$ were rows. **Is this correct**?If yes, why? This reasonment would bring me considering the design matrix $\Phi$ as the $N \times K$ matrix

$$\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}\phi_1(x_1) & \dots & \phi_K(x_1)\\
\vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ \phi_1(x_N) & \dots & \phi_K(x_N) \end{bmatrix}$$

So why does he write that $n$-th row corresponds to $\bf \phi(\textbf{x}_n)^T$?

Also how the hell does he obtain the 6.5 by substitution? I really can't figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is way too late, but maybe it helps other people.

Assume we have a set of inputs
$X = \left\{\textbf{x}_1,\cdots ,\textbf{x}_N \right\}$,
$\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}x_1& \cdots & x_D \\\end{matrix}\right]^T$,  and a linear regression model of the form:

$$y(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w})=\sum_{j=0}^{M-1}w_j \phi_j(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x})$$

Let $\boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x})=\left[\begin{matrix}\phi_0(\mathbf{x})& \cdots& \phi_j(\mathbf{x}) & \cdots & \phi_{M-1}(\mathbf{x}) \\\end{matrix}\right]^T$
and $\phi_j$ be the j-th (nonlinear) basis function that returns a scalar value.
 For example, for a scalar x, the monomial:
$\phi_j(\mathbf{x}) = \textbf{x}^{j}$
And for a vector $\mathbf{x}$:
$\phi_j(\mathbf{x}) = \left\| \mathbf{x} \right\|^{j}=\left ( \sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_D^2}\right )^j$

The error function for the parameter w with some regularization term $\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}$ is equal to:
$E(\mathbf{w})
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left( \mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x_n}) 
- t_n\right)^2+\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}$

Quoting the book, note that $J(\mathbf{w})$ is $E(\mathbf{w})$ here:

> If we set the gradient of $J(\mathbf{w})$ with respect to $\mathbf{w}$ equal to zero, we see that the solution for $\mathbf{w}$ takes the form of a linear combination of the vectors $\boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_n)$, with coefficients that are functions of $\mathbf{w}$, of the form
> $\mathbf{w} = [\cdots]=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_n)=\boldsymbol\Phi^T \mathbf{a}$ (6.3)

As we can see $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_n)$ is a linear combination of the vectors $\boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_n)$ scaled with a scalar value $a_n$. Thus, we can rewrite the sum as follows:

$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_n) 
= a_1 \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_1) + \cdots + a_N \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_N) 
= \left(\mathbf{a}^T \boldsymbol\Phi\right)^T
\equiv \boldsymbol\Phi^T \mathbf{a}$

with
$$\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}\phi_0(\mathbf{x}_1) & \dots & \phi_{M-1}(\mathbf{x}_1)\\
\vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ \phi_0(\mathbf{x}_N) & \dots & \phi_{M-1}(\mathbf{x}_N) \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_1)^T\\ \vdots \\ \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x}_N)^T \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{a}=\left[\begin{matrix}a_1& \cdots & a_N \\\end{matrix}\right]^T$$

Do not get confused by the term $\left(\mathbf{a}^T \boldsymbol\Phi\right)^T$. The important part is $\mathbf{a}^T \boldsymbol\Phi$, where the result is a row vector $\mathbf{v}^T=\left[\begin{matrix}v_0& \cdots & v_j & \cdots & v_{M-1} \\\end{matrix}\right]$, where each element j is the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \boldsymbol\phi_j(\mathbf{x}_n)$. We then take the transpose to get the same dimension as the column vector $\mathbf{w}$.

---

Rewriting the error function $E(\mathbf{w})$ gives:

$$E(\mathbf{w})=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left( \mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x_n}) 
- t_n\right)^2
+\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left( \mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x_n}) 
- t_n\right)^T \left( \mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\phi(\mathbf{x_n}) 
- t_n\right)
+\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left( \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{w} 
- \mathbf{t}\right)^T \left( \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{w} 
- \mathbf{t}\right)
+\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x})^T 
- \mathbf{t}^T\right) \left( \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{w} 
- \mathbf{t}\right)
+\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x})^T \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{w}
-\mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x})^T\mathbf{t}
-\mathbf{t}^T\boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{w}
+\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{t}
\right) 
+\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x})^T \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{w}
-2\mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol\Phi(\mathbf{x})^T\mathbf{t}
+\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{t}
\right) 
+\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}
$$

Inserting the estimator $\hat{\mathbf{w}}=\boldsymbol\Phi^T \mathbf{a}$ into the error function $E(\mathbf{w})$ gives the dual representation $E(\mathbf{a})$ (eq. 6.5):

$$E(\mathbf{a}) = E(\mathbf{w}=\hat{\mathbf{w}}) = 
\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{a}^T \boldsymbol\Phi \boldsymbol\Phi^T \boldsymbol\Phi \boldsymbol\Phi^T \mathbf{a} 
- \mathbf{a}^T \boldsymbol\Phi \boldsymbol\Phi^T \mathbf{t} 
+ \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{t}^T \mathbf{t} 
+ \frac{\lambda}{2} \mathbf{a}^T \boldsymbol\Phi \boldsymbol\Phi^T \mathbf{a} $$